# Hyperlinks on a picture or map

Tags: ms-office

I would like to take a picture, in this case a map of houses, and insert links over each house that shows owner details. Also have a list of owners that when I click on their name takes me to their house on the picture.

Comment: Are you doing this on a Word doc?

Comment: what ever lets me do it the easiest.

Comment: or whatever application is easiest.

Comment: You are using a image as a map, not an interactive one right?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Map of houses]
Say that is your map of houses. Whatever software you are using; Word, PowerPoint, Publisher, etc; you can add textboxes. Make a textbox for each of the houses and place it above the each of the houses. Make these textboxes set to "In Front of Text" so that you can put them above the map. Make the size of the textboxes the same as that of the houses. Then right click the textbox and click "Hyperlink". You can then add a website address or a link to another document.

To add link for the names of people, highlight the text. Right click the highlighted text and click "Hyperlink". Again, you can add the website link if wanted.

If you want the name to go to the house, you will have to create "bookmarks". Right click the text boxes we created before for each house. Then go to Insert > Links group > Bookmark. This is the screen:

[image: Adding Bookmarks]

Then type a name for that bookmark **without spaces** (e.g. House_1). Then click "Add". After that, highlight the name of the person, right click, and then click "Hyperlink". Then go to "Place in this Document". There should be a bookmark called "House_1" (or whatever you named it). Click that and then click OK like this:

[image]

Now each time you click the name (in my example, "Jack"), the Word Document will automatically scroll to that house. You can do the same in PowerPoint as well. Any clarification, leave a comment.